# apache2 ServerAlias showing strange behaviour

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to setup two websites on a single apache2 server.
one the main site and the other is a cloud server

the first is defined in 000-default.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www-sites/main/

<Directory  /var/www-sites/main/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">                                                                       
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

The second is in 100-cloud.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www-sites/OwnCloud
ServerName cloud.example.com
ServerAlias www.cloud.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost



<Directory  /var/www-sites/OwnCloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">                                                                       
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

ServerSignature On
```

Now here is the strange thing :

in this example the www.cloud.example.com goos to the default ( example.com ) site and not to cloud.example.com

if i change the name from the first conf file to zzz-default.conf the www.example.com goos to the cloud.example.com

also if I change the files so it states :

```
ServerName www.cloud.example.com
ServerAlias cloud.example.com
```

cloud.example wil be directed to the default as if ServerAlias is NOT working

what am i doing wrong ? on my other server this works just fine.

thanks

extra info : the output of `apachectl -S`
 is:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
             alias example.com
     port 80 namevhost sys.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:50)
     port 80 namevhost cloud.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-cloud.conf:1)
             alias www.cloud.example.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect you do not have a `NameVirtualHost` directive, because you describe that the first VirtualHost takes over the second. May be you could get some further info by running `apachectl -S`. Add the output of these commands to your post if it's not the `NameVirtualHost` directive that is missing.

Comment: I checked it and looks like `NameVirtualHost` is defined, I compared it with the server that is running well and it looks very similar.